# Script tags seem to automatically be loaded async on mobile

Tags: javascript

this is a weird one.

I have several `<script>...</script>` tags with inline code in my page that were used to logically separate pieces of code. For instance: `<script id='prepareA'>...</script>` `<script id='docReadyStuff'>...</script>`.

Now, what is happening is that sometimes a function declared in a script tag is not visible in another one, even though the function script tag comes before in code.

To better explain this, consider this piece of code:

```
<script>

function DoSomething() {
    alert("something");
}

</script>

<script id=blockA>

function Foo() {

$("#btn").on("click", function() {

    alert("calling DoSomething");
    DoSomething();

});

}

</script>

<script>
$(function() {

    // Calling Foo() from within
    // ready, so any access to DOM from Foo
    // *should* be safe!
    Foo();

});
</script>
```

Now, on every desktop browser, this works fine. However, on mobile chrome and safari for **iPhone**, when the button `btn` is pressed, it says `DoSomething is undefined`. On Android it works fine.

I have no idea why this happens since DoSomething is **clearly defined before** the button event handler is event attached. Now, if I move `DoSomething` to the line before `Foo` is defined, then it works.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

*iPhone 5s, iOs 9.3.5; Mobile Chrome 55.0.2883.79;

Comment: Very strange! Are these inline scripts,or you are using the `src` attribute? and are you positive you are not using the `async` or `defer` attributes on script tag? This kinda sounds like a browser bug to me, looking forward to seeing an answer.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure, I triple checked it. Also, yes, they are all inline, just like in the example. Not sure if it is a browser bug thou, since Safari also fails.

Comment: Chrome on iOS uses a system webview (WKWebView) so it kind of makes sense it would exhibit the same problem as Safari iOS.